# Merging every 4 cells and adding the data for Electricity Bill

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, merge

I downloaded some data from my electricity bill that is organized in 15 minute increments. There's way too many data points, so I'm looking to find a way to merge down this data to show usage in 1 hour chunks (and maybe even 1 day chunks if necessary). Is there an easy way to merge every 4 cells together, adding together the usage?

Here's a visual of the data I'm dealing with.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have a look at PowerQuery. Probably possible there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1)** Add a helper column with the formula `=B2+C2` in cell `F2` and copy it down your data.

[image]

**Step 2)** Add a pivot table

[image]

**Step 3)** Add the `DateTime` field to the `Rows` section of the pivot table

[image]

**Step 4)** Right-click on that field in the pivot table, click "Group", make sure only "Days" and "Hours" are selected, and click "OK"

[image]
[image]

**Step 5)** Add whatever other fields you want. For instance, add `Usage` to the `Values` section.

[image]

Comment: ...........a very thorough answer

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Coming from you, I'll take that as a compliment. I considered cutting it down to avoid the "this is not a code-writing service" but wanted to provide the new contributor with a complete answer in the hopes they'd stick around, learn, and contribute themselves.

Comment: @EngineerToast  You are a god among men (and women). Never have I ever received such a complete walk-through response. I am humbled by your kindness!

Comment: @Dan Welcome to StackExchange!